# How to create a 3D image with a frame around?

Tags: html, css, image, css-transforms

From an image I have to show it as a painting and also put a frame on it (all this with a 3D perspective).
This is how the image should look, like a painting:

[image: Image like a painting]

This is how it should look with the frame:

[image: Image like a peinting with frame]

Here is the code I have, so far only the part that looks like a picture.

```css
.sh {
  --valorshadow: -20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  filter: drop-shadow(var(--valorshadow));
}

.box {
  --x: 10px;
  --y: 30px;
  clip-path: polygon( 0 calc(var(--x) + var(--y)), var(--y) var(--y), calc(100% - var(--y)) var(--y), calc(100% - var(--y)) calc(100% - var(--y)), var(--y) calc(100% - var(--y)), 0 calc(100% - var(--x) - var(--y)));
  margin: 30px;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(35deg);
  outline: var(--y) solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  outline-offset: calc(-1*var(--y));
}
```

```html
<div class="sh">
  <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/391/773/307/art-artistic-artwork-creative-wallpaper-preview.jpg" class="box">
</div>
```

How can I make the frame and make it look with a 3D perspective?

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
We are 2 people, it is a teamwork of the school, it is a database assaigment, but we do not know much about html and css so we are having difficulties doing the visual part of the project.   We have to do like a small art store, when the other girl doing the project told me that you answered the question, I also wanted to upload this question to see if there was luck. Hope so. Thanks for answering the previous question.
 :)

Comment: is this what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/ob3nxph1/?

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
Yes, just that, thank you very very very much. Really thanks.

Comment: added another idea to my answer for a better rendring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can simply adjust the `clip-path` to keep the outline visible. Use the one in the first snippet of [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62379638/8620333)

```css
.box {
  --x: 10px;
  --y: 30px;

  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--x), var(--y) 0,
      100% 0, 100% 100%,
      var(--y) 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--x)));
  margin: 30px;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(35deg);
  outline: var(--y) solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  outline-offset: calc(-1*var(--y));

}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/728/600"  class="box">
```

Or like below to have a more realistic frame:

```css
.box {
  --x: 10px;
  --y: 30px;
  --o:10px;

  clip-path:polygon(
       0 calc(var(--x) + var(--y)),var(--y) var(--y),
       calc(100% - var(--y)) var(--y),calc(100% - var(--y)) calc(100% - var(--y)),
       var(--y) calc(100% - var(--y)),0 calc(100% - var(--x) - var(--y)));
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) var(--y), #fff 0);
          mask:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) var(--y), #fff 0);
  margin: 30px;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(35deg);
  outline: calc(var(--y) + var(--o)) solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  outline-offset: calc(-1*(var(--y) + var(--o)));

}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/728/600"  class="box">
```

[image: CSS 3D iframe image]